# How can I force hyphenation in chapter titles?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, hyphenation

I have a (German and English) document, which uses the scrbook class fromt he KOMA package, with long German words in the chapter titles. 
I would like Latex to hyphenate those words when necessary, but I do not know how to do this.

A minimal example looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\hyphenation{men-schen-rechts-ana-logen}
\selectlanguage{english}
\hyphenation{}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\chapter{Noch viel viel mehr zu menschenrechtsanalogen Dingen}
\chapter{Noch viel viel mehr zu men\-schen\-rechts\-ana\-logen Dingen}
\end{document}
```

I run it with `xelatex hyph.tex` and I get a chapter line like this:

[image]

and I would like to have the word "menschenrechtsanalogen" to get hyphenated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Redefine `\raggedsection` (see p. 91--92 of the English version of the `KOMA-Script` manual). One option is to typeset sectioning titles justified:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{}% default is \raggedright
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\hyphenation{men-schen-rechts-ana-logen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Noch viel viel mehr zu menschenrechtsanalogen Dingen}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use the `\RaggedRight` command of the [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package (this combines alignment to the left and possibility of hyphenation):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\RaggedRight}% default is \raggedright
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\hyphenation{men-schen-rechts-ana-logen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Noch viel viel mehr zu menschenrechtsanalogen Dingen}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that both approaches can be combined with specifying hyphenation points *manually* (with `\-`) in the argument of `\section`. The motivation to do so is that there may be hyphenation points which are acceptable in the running text, but somewhat out of place in sectioning titles.

Comment: ugh.  the section heading lines are unattractively spacy.  better just to lower the penalty on hyphenation, rather than wiping out the other desirable features of `\raggedsection`.  (i'm not in a position to look up the details at the moment.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The `ragged2e` option should be more attractive.

Comment: Is there a way to get hyphenation in one heading and keep the default otherwise?